# Unable to run Jquery Tablesorter Plug-in

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I have spend over an hour trying to figure out what's wrong here.  I see the HTML table when I load the page on a browser from my local server, but I can't do any sorting and the table itself looks nothing like the example at the Tablesorter website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
</head>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this piece

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

From: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to modify your code :

1. You have to initialize your tablesorter jQuery plugin

   $(document).ready(function() 
       { 
           $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
       } 
   );

I advice you for the next time to read the documentation of your jQuery plugin [(http://tablesorter.com/docs/](http://tablesorter.com/docs/))

Your entire code here :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Last Name</th> 
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Email</th> 
        <th>Due</th> 
        <th>Web Site</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>John</td> 
        <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Bach</td> 
        <td>Frank</td> 
        <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Doe</td> 
        <td>Jason</td> 
        <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
        <td>$100.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Conway</td> 
        <td>Tim</td> 
        <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
    </table>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() 
      { 
       $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
      } 
      );
     </script> 
    </html>
```